# The enrichWP function is no longer recognized in `comparecluster()` (clusterProfiler R package)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, r-package

I have been using clusterProfiler for quite a while, specifically the `compareCluster()` function. I have used `enrichKEGG()`and `enrichWP()`for my workflow since January 2023. But now `fun = "enrichWP"` isn't recognized in the `comparecluster()` function. Indeed when checking the R doc, it does now state for the `fun` argument : `One of "groupGO", "enrichGO", "enrichKEGG", "enrichDO" or "enrichPathway" . Users can also supply their own function.`

Previously, when applying `compareCluster()` function with `fun = "enrichWP"`, the function performed Over-Representation Analysis (ORA) on each individual group/cluster of genes based on biological pathways found within the Wikipathways database. The result being a `compareClusterResult`
Now, when I try to reapply it, I get a error message :

`Last error message: objet 'enrichWP' not found`

*Does anyone have any information upon this subject ?*
*Why has it been removed ?* If so, *for what reason ?* And *will it return ?*

Thank you in advance for any help answering me questions !